# SQL Server : column name of max of several columns for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, ssms

I have a table called `campaigns` that shows the number of 'tiles' each category is displayed in in an email campaign, like below

```
    campaign_id     categoryA_tiles   categoryB_tiles   categoryC_tiles ... cateogory Z_tiles
        1               5                7                    4         ...      4
        2               4                4                    9         ...      1
```

I need to add 3 columns to this table that show the 3 most frequently occurring categories (i.e. the column names) for each email campaign. For example I would like the result to look like this

```
campaign_id ...  category_1    category_2    category_3
    1       ...   categoryB    categoryA     categoryZ
    2       ...   categoryC    categoryA     categoryB
```

Note that there may be ties as in the second row, in which case I'd like them to be displayed from left to right.

This is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742616/get-column-name-which-has-the-max-value-in-a-row-sql) but I'm using SSMS 2012 rather than MySQl. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743305/5960498) is what I'm after but it is incompatible with SSMS. To be specific, the error I can't fix is how `@rownum` is defined and used.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be easy to help, if you include the script for Table and dummy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax between SQL Server and others is not the same (especially with row number - see the docs for [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)).

Try this:

```
DECLARE @campaigns TABLE (campaign_id int, categoryA_tiles int, categoryB_tiles int,  categoryC_tiles int, categoryZ_tiles int)

INSERT INTO @campaigns VALUES
(1,5,7,4,4),
(2,4,4,9,1),
(3,2,5,9,10),
(4,1,8,9,11)

SELECT
  t2.campaign_id,
  max(case when t2.RowNumber=1 then t2.name end) as 'highest value',
  max(case when t2.RowNumber=2 then t2.name end) as '2nd highest value',
  max(case when t2.RowNumber=3 then t2.name end) as '3rd highest value',
  max(case when t2.RowNumber=4 then t2.name end) as '4th highest value'
FROM 
    (SELECT campaign_id, name, amt,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY campaign_id ORDER BY amt DESC) AS RowNumber 
      FROM 
        (SELECT campaign_id, categoryA_tiles AS amt, 'categoryA_tiles' AS name FROM @campaigns UNION 
         SELECT campaign_id, categoryB_tiles AS amt, 'categoryB_tiles' AS name FROM @campaigns UNION
         SELECT campaign_id, categoryC_tiles AS amt, 'categoryC_tiles' AS name FROM @campaigns UNION
         SELECT campaign_id, categoryZ_tiles AS amt, 'categoryZ_tiles' AS name FROM @campaigns) t1) t2 
GROUP BY t2.campaign_id
```

The answer will be:

```
campaign_id    highest value       2nd highest value    3rd highest value   4th highest value
    1          categoryB_tiles     categoryA_tiles      categoryC_tiles     categoryZ_tiles
    2          categoryC_tiles     categoryA_tiles      categoryB_tiles     categoryZ_tiles
    3          categoryZ_tiles     categoryC_tiles      categoryB_tiles     categoryA_tiles
    4          categoryZ_tiles     categoryC_tiles      categoryB_tiles     categoryA_tiles
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks, and relatively easy to understand for me (only recently learning SQL)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can solve this using `UNPIVOT`, please try the below script

```
DECLARE @campaigns TABLE (campaign_id int, categoryA_tiles int, categoryB_tiles int,  categoryC_tiles int, categoryZ_tiles int)

INSERT INTO @campaigns VALUES (1,5,7,4,4),(2,4,4,9,1)

SELECT T.campaign_id,
        MAX((CASE WHEN RowNumber=1 THEN [tVal] END)) AS Category1,
        MAX((CASE WHEN RowNumber=2 THEN [tVal] END)) AS Category2,
        MAX((CASE WHEN RowNumber=3 THEN [tVal] END)) AS Category3
FROM    (
    SELECT campaign_id,tVal,MaxVal,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY campaign_id ORDER BY MaxVal DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM @campaigns t1
    UNPIVOT ( MaxVal FOR tVal IN ( categoryA_tiles, categoryB_tiles, categoryC_tiles ,categoryZ_tiles) ) AS u
)   T
GROUP BY T.campaign_id
```

Here you can add/remove more column/category as per your requirement (or can join with tables - campaigns or other tables - for additional columns).

Result:

```
campaign_id Category1       Category2       Category3
1           categoryB_tiles categoryA_tiles categoryC_tiles
2           categoryC_tiles categoryA_tiles categoryB_tiles
```