# Minimum Value column calculation by grouping total in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, min

I have a table named `calcu`

```
id  date       name     s1       s2      s3     s4       min_value
1   2/10/2017  dicky    7        4       8      9       [4]
2   2/10/2017  acton    12      15       17     19      [15]
3   2/10/2017  adney    28      13       19     10      [13]
```

If I total all fields in a single date then the result will be

```
    2/10/2017           47      32      44      38
```

Here minimum value is `32`. It means minimum value column is `s2`. That's why I input `s2 field value` in `min_value` field in table `calcu` respectively.

I need how will I complete min_value field through SQL query?

I am using MYSQL database.

Plz show SQL query and query result.

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc ..) which u r using.

Comment: You can see this ... It can be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742616/get-column-name-which-has-the-max-value-in-a-row-sql

Comment: Elaborate your question more. What is your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find the column with the minimum sum first and then use that column in your query. So you need a subquery where you compare each sum with the others and remember the column name. Then in the main query use that column name to check which value to show.

```
select 
  c.id, c.date, c.name, c.s1, c.s2, c.s3, c.s4, 
  case 
    when col.colname = 's1' then c.s1
    when col.colname = 's2' then c.s2
    when col.colname = 's3' then c.s3
    when col.colname = 's4' then c.s4
  end as min_value
from calcu c
cross join
(
  select
    case 
      when sum(s1) <= sum(s2) and sum(s1) <= sum(s3) and sum(s1) <= sum(s4) then 's1'
      when sum(s2) <= sum(s1) and sum(s2) <= sum(s3) and sum(s2) <= sum(s4) then 's2'
      when sum(s3) <= sum(s1) and sum(s3) <= sum(s2) and sum(s3) <= sum(s4) then 's3'
      else                                                                       's4'
    end as colname
  from calcu
) col;
```

The altered SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31579c/3

Comment: My problem has been solved. Now May I get row wise total value? I means in a new column `total`, it will be (7+4+8+9) = 28 where id=1, (12+15+17+19)=63 where id=2, (28+13+19+10)=70 where id=3 respectively.

Comment: Why have you put `sum(c.s1 + c.s2 + c.s3 + c.s4)`? It's simply `c.s1 + c.s2 + c.s3 + c.s4` without `sum`, because you only want to add values in the row itself, not aggregate data over several rows. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31579c/40

Comment: I have understood my mistake. one more question if don't mind,   Is it possible to set a column named `min_total` where value will be min_total*4 i.e. 4*4 = 16 where id is 1.

Comment: You want a factor of 4 vs. 1 in case of `id = 1`. Use another case expression for this and multiply: `case when c.id = 1 then 4 else 1 end * case when col.colname ... end as min_value`.

Comment: Actually I do not understand how will I create the multiply case query.. for the `min_total` column.

Comment: With your suggestion I completed last question. this is my last question.. how will I get a `final` column which will be `total` value - `min_total` value respectively with this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31579c/44.

Comment: All you did is have another column min_total which is 4 * min_value. You said, however, you only wanted it for ID 1. I supposed you wanted the min_value values, except for ID 1 where you wanted it fourfold. This seems not to be the case now. I suggest you make this a new request. Show the query and results you have and the results you want instead in that request and it will be much easier to give you the correct answer.